# What percent of even positive integers are divisible by 6, 20, 28 and 70?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am curious about the problem:

What percent of even positive integers are divisible by 6, 20, 28 and 70?

Can you help me to answer the question?

What I know is that if we denote by $p$ the percentage then:

$p>33\%$ Since 33% of even positive integers are divisible by 6.

Also a problem may arise since the integer 60 is both divisible by 6 and 20.

Comment: Hint : Least common multiple.

Comment: Hi, how can we use LCM to solve this problem? Can you give a particular example? Say for instance, what percentage of positive integers are divisible by 3 or 5. We know that we have a 33 percent which are divisible by 3. And 20 percent  that are divisible by 5. Now the LCM of 3 and 5 is 15. There are 6.66 percent positive ntegers that are divisible by 15. So the answer is 33+20-6.66 percent?

Comment: Exactly, but one clarification : do you want numbers that are divisible by *at least one* of them , or by *all* of them? Because from the question it looks like you want *all* to be divisible by the number, in which case the LCM helps. Otherwise, if it is *at least one*, then you will need an inclusion-exclusion argument.

Comment: Thanks again. Thanks also for clarification. What I mean in the question is divisible by 6 or 20 or 28 or 70.

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer.

Comment: There is no uniform probability distribution on the positive numbers. This question, or a variant of it, gets asked very often; it has no answer unless you clarify what you mean by "percentage". Percentage with respect to what probability distribution? Or else how are you taking the limit of percentages with respect to uniform distributions on finite sets?

Comment: Hi Patrick. Kindly enlighten me on "with respect to what Probability Distribution"? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the chances of divisibility by a number (we'll divide by half later) of $6,20,28,70$ respectively, is $\frac 16 , ... ,\frac 1{70}$.

For numbers divisible by both $6$ and $20$, it is a multiple of their lcm, which is $60$, so one must exclude this case since it gets counted twice, by subtracting the reciprocals of all pairwise least common multiples.

So far, it's looking like:
$$
\frac 16 + \frac 1{20} + \frac1{28} + \frac 1{70} - \left(\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}(6,20)} +  ... + \frac 1{\operatorname{lcm}(28,70)}\right)
$$

Now, note that if something is a multiple of all of $6,20,28$, then it gets added thrice (by taking $6,20,28$), and then subtracted thrice (when we remove lcm of $6,20$, $6,28$ and $20,28$). Since we need to include these again, we have to add the lcms of all these quantities taken three at a time.

So then we get:
$$
\frac 16 + \frac 1{20} + \frac1{28} + \frac 1{70} - \left(\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}(6,20)} +  ... + \frac 1{\operatorname{lcm}(28,70)}\right) + \left( \frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}(6,20,28)} +  ... + \frac 1{\operatorname{lcm}(20,28,70)}\right)
$$

Now, if something is a multiple of all four of these, we see this gets subtracted $4$ times at first, then gets removed $6$ times (pairwise lcm), only to get added $4$ times more (lcm  of three quantities out of four). So in all, it's been counted twice, so we need to remove one copy. Hence, the final answer:
$$
\frac 16 + \frac 1{20} + \frac1{28} + \frac 1{70} - \left(\frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}(6,20)} +  ... + \frac 1{\operatorname{lcm}(28,70)}\right) + \left( \frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm}(6,20,28)} +  ... + \frac 1{\operatorname{lcm}(20,28,70)}\right) - \frac{1}{\operatorname{lcm} (6,20,28,70)}
$$

The answer is then: (I'll write it out completely)
$$
\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{28} +\frac{1}{70} - \frac{1}{60} - \frac 1{84} - \frac 1{210} - \frac{1}{140} - \frac{1}{140} - \frac {1}{140} + \frac{1}{420} + \frac{1}{420} + \frac{1}{420} + \frac{1}{140} - \frac 1{420}
$$

You can see why I don't want to evaluate this, but I hope you get the principle behind this answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Do we need to multiply the answer by 2? For we are looking over the set of even positive integer? Thanks

Comment: We need to multiply by $2$ as it stands. Please read the comment by Patrick above, I completely disregarded it when I was writing this answer.

Comment: Thanks again. My last question will be. Is it true that in general given $n$ number of sets, $n$ taken odds are positive while $n$ taken even is negative? For instance in the answer, 4 taken 1 is positive while 4 taken 2 is negative 4 taken 3 values are positive and 4 taken 4 value is negative.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1):

The LCM of $6, 20, 28, 70$ is $420$.
Let $A_k =  ${$kn : n \in \mathbb{N} \space \text{ and } kn \le 420$}
And $A_{k,m} = A_k \bigcup A_m$

$$6 = 3 * 2$$
$$20 = 5 * 2 * 2$$
$$28 = 7 * 2 * 2$$
$$70 = 7 * 5 * 2$$

$$|A_6| = 70$$
$$|A_{20}| = 21$$
$$|A_{28}| = 15$$
$$|A_{70}| = 6$$
The above were found just by dividing $420$ by $k$

$$|A_{6,20}| = 7$$
$$|A_{6,28}| = 5$$
$$|A_{6,70}| = 2$$

$$|A_{20,28}| = 3$$
$$|A_{20,70}| = 3$$
$$|A_{28,70}| = 3$$

$$|A_{6,20,28}| = 1$$
$$|A_{6,20,70}| = 1$$
$$|A_{6,28,70}| = 1$$

$$|A_{20,28,70}| = 3$$

$$|A_{6,20,28,70}| = 1$$
Everything else above was found by observing the prime factorization of each of the numbers in question. For example, $|A_{6,20}| = 7$ because $6*5*2 = (3*2)*5*2 = 3*(5*2*2) = 3*20$, so $|A_{6,20}| = |A_{20}|/3 = 7$.

Using the relationship between unions and intersections now, we get:
$$|A_6 \bigcap A_{20} \bigcap A_{28} \bigcap A_{70}| = 70 + 21 + 15 + 6 -7 - 5 - 2 - 3 - 3 - 3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 - 3 = 94$$

$P = 94/420$

If I have correctly interpreted what you mean by "percent of positive even numbers", then the answer you seek is:

$P = 94/210 = 47/105$

Which is about $44.8\text{%}$